# forEach/functional recursion and returning values

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I have an array which looks like this:

```
['id1/id2', 'id3', 'id4/id5/id6']
```

Although it may have more than 3 entries, or more split values (/ things) - these may change depending on the state of the app but this is a standard example.

I am trying to output:

```
[
    ['id1', 'id3', 'id4'],
    ['id1', 'id3', 'id5'],
    ['id1', 'id3', 'id6'],
    ['id2', 'id3', 'id4'],
    ['id2', 'id3', 'id5'],
    ['id2', 'id3', 'id6']
]
```

I think a forEach loop can be used to recurse through but I got stuck on the syntax, and so tried a standard functional recursive tpye. I also was unsure about the return procedure to generate the output. What I have so far is:

```
singleOptionStemGenerator(route: string[]): [string[]] {

    let returnArray: [string[]];

    route.forEach((options: string) => {
        // split into the various options
        let splitOption: string[] = options.split('/');

        splitOption.forEach((str: string) => {
            if(route.length > 1) {
                this.singleOptionStemGenerator(route.splice(0, 1));
            } else {
                return str;
            }
        })
    });

    return returnArray;
}
```

But I am not sure how to amalgamate the ID values into a new array, and then add that to a new array overall.

EDIT: The solution given below for myself was a little dense, so I went through and made it a function and fully annotated it. I also made it typescript (which I use). The solution is all what the answer this, this just feel sanitzed for easier reading and learning: https://codepen.io/bogomip/pen/LYLjrxa

Comment: Hello, is the number of the elements in one column always equal to the lowest common multiple ?

Comment: Hi Dariosicily, yes, I guess the output will always have x * y * z items if we have [ x, y, z ] items in the array. Maybe in this way its possible to create that output array, interesting thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is usually called the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).  With a helper function that computes those, this becomes almost trivial.

Here is one version:

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs = undefined
    ? []
  : xss.length == 0
    ? xs .map (x => [x])
  : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

const separate = (xs) => 
  cartesian (xs .map (x => x .split ('/')))

console .log (separate (['id1/id2', 'id3', 'id4/id5/id6']))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

### Update

A comment made it clear that this code is somewhat dense.  Part of that is my penchant for expression-only coding.  For those more used to expression-and-statement-style Javascript, this version might be more familiar:

```js
const cartesian = (xss) => {
  if (xss .length == 0) {
    return []
  }
  const first = xss [0] 
  const rest = xss .slice (1)
  if (rest .length == 0) {
    return first .map (x => [x])
  }
  const cartesianEnd = cartesian (rest)
  return first .flatMap (
    x => cartesianEnd .map (ys => [x, ...ys])
  )
}
```

If that style is more to your liking, then that may also help explain the code as I wrote it.  Except that... typing that out made me realize that there was a horrible inefficiency in my first approach.  Unfortunately the fix adds some complexity, but it is clearly worthwhile:

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs = undefined
    ? []
  : xss.length == 0
    ? xs .map (x => [x])
  : ((yss = cartesian (xss)) => xs .flatMap (x => yss .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))) ()
```

The problem was that I was recalculating the product of the remaining arrays for each element of my current array.  These don't change, and we should do this only once.  Ahh for real `let`-bindings in JS!  We could do this in many different manners, but this one is not too bad.

Comment: I changed the codepen with the solution, made it a function (as is my penchant! :)) and annotated it for anybody who might like some guidance on this solution: https://codepen.io/bogomip/pen/LYLjrxa?editors=0012

Comment: Nice!  Do note that "made it a function" is a bit odd here.  It was already a function, using the [Arrow Function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).